# Random chars on MAX7219 with Micropython SoftSPI on ESP8266 (ESP-07 4MiB Flash)

Tags: esp8266, spi, micropython

I am trying to use MAX7219 7 segment display with Micropython (v 1.20.0) on ESP-07. I am using the driver as written by pdwerryhouse (https://github.com/pdwerryhouse/max7219_8digit). I have downloaded and flashed the two files: max7219_8digit.py and README.rst (renamed and flashed as main.py). I also have a boot.py with bare minimum code. I have used a level translator, based on MOSFET N7000, as described in many websites, which is fully functional (tested with ESP-07 and 5V LEDs).
Connections are (ESP -> MAX7219): GPIO4 -> SCK (CLK); GPIO2 -> MOSI(DIN); GPIO5 -> SS(CS) , all through a 3.3V to 5 V level translator.
I have sufficient experience, being a retired electronics engineer with a 'C' background, to wire up the devices properly, so no issues there. I am a newbie in Micropython, except that I had switched some LEDs (5v) using the Pin class on the same ESP-07 and got it to connect to my home WiFi as STA.
I have reproduced the codes as flashed on my device. Please assist me in getting the SPI, both hardware and SoftSPI to work, I will be grateful.
I also wish to understand the statement: self.spi.write(bytearray([register, value])) in the method set_register below. I tried to find on the web, but got only standard definitions of bytearray(value, attribute...). How does this statement write two values on the max7219?

boot.py

```
**# boot.py**
#put all frequently used initialising code here - WiFi, Sockets, GPIO etc.
#functional codes in main.py

try:
 import usocket as socket
except:
 import socket

from machine import Pin, SPI
import network

import esp
import esp
esp.osdebug(None)

ssid = 'Mw3gHome24'
password = 'AzmH%1001&'

station = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)type here
```

**main.py**

```
# Connections:
# SCK (CLK) -> GPIO4 (D2)
# MOSI (DIN) -> GPIO2 (D4)
# SS (CS) -> GPIO5 (D1)

from machine import Pin, SPI  #also tried SoftSPI
import max7219_8digit

# the max7219 doesn't use the MISO, but unfortunately SoftSPI requires that
# we specify it anyway
spi = SoftSPI(baudrate=100000, polarity=1, phase=0, sck=Pin(4), mosi=Pin(2), miso=Pin(0))  #also tried polarity = 0, as required by MAX7219

ss = Pin(5, Pin.OUT)

display = max7219_8digit.Display(spi, ss)
display.write_to_buffer('12345678')   #also reduced the number of chars to see if it works
display.display()
```

max7219_8digit.py

```
# Licence: GPLv3
# Copyright 2017 Paul Dwerryhouse <paul@dwerryhouse.com.au>

CHAR_MAP = { 
    '0': 0x7e, '1': 0x30, '2': 0x6d, '3': 0x79,
    '4': 0x33, '5': 0x5b, '6': 0x5f, '7': 0x70,
    '8': 0x7f, '9': 0x7b, 'a': 0x77, 'b': 0x1f,
    'c': 0x4e, 'd': 0x3d, 'e': 0x4f, 'f': 0x47,
    'g': 0x7b, 'h': 0x37, 'i': 0x30, 'j': 0x3c,
    'k': 0x57, 'l': 0x0e, 'm': 0x54, 'n': 0x15,
    'o': 0x1d, 'p': 0x67, 'q': 0x73, 'r': 0x05,
    's': 0x5b, 't': 0x0f, 'u': 0x1c, 'v': 0x3e,
    'w': 0x2a, 'x': 0x37, 'y': 0x3b, 'z': 0x6d,
    'A': 0x77, 'B': 0x1f, 'C': 0x4e, 'D': 0x3d, 
    'E': 0x4f, 'F': 0x47, 'G': 0x7b, 'H': 0x37, 
    'I': 0x30, 'J': 0x3c, 'K': 0x57, 'L': 0x0e, 
    'M': 0x54, 'N': 0x15, 'O': 0x1d, 'P': 0x67, 
    'Q': 0x73, 'R': 0x05, 'S': 0x5b, 'T': 0x0f, 
    'U': 0x1c, 'V': 0x3e, 'W': 0x2a, 'X': 0x37, 
    'Y': 0x3b, 'Z': 0x6d, ' ': 0x00, '-': 0x01, 
    '\xb0': 0x63, '.': 0x80
}#this is a dictionary with {key:value} elements. Use get() method with 'key' as 
#argument to retreive the 'value'

REG_NO_OP           = 0x00
REG_DIGIT_BASE      = 0x01
REG_DECODE_MODE     = 0x09
REG_INTENSITY       = 0x0a
REG_SCAN_LIMIT      = 0x0b
REG_SHUTDOWN        = 0x0c
REG_DISPLAY_TEST    = 0x0f

class Display:

    def __init__(self, spi, ss, intensity=4):
        self.spi = spi
        self.ss = ss
        self.buffer = bytearray(8) #create array of 8 bytes and init to NULL
        self.intensity = intensity
        self.reset()
    
    def reset(self):
        self.set_register(REG_DECODE_MODE, 0)
        self.set_register(REG_INTENSITY, self.intensity)
        self.set_register(REG_SCAN_LIMIT, 7)
        self.set_register(REG_DISPLAY_TEST, 0)
        self.set_register(REG_SHUTDOWN, 1)

    def set_register(self, register, value):
        self.ss.off()
        self.spi.write(bytearray([register, value]))
        self.ss.on()

    def decode_char(self, c):
        d = CHAR_MAP.get(c)  #get() uses 'key' as arg to retrieve 'value' from dictionary
        return d if d != None else ' '

    def write_to_buffer(self, s): # 's' is a string to be displayed
        l = len(s)
        if l < 8:    #(my comment)if less than 8 bytes, insert padding on right of 's' to make 8 bytes
            s = "%-8s" % s 
        for i in range(0,8):
            self.buffer[7-i] = self.decode_char(s[i])  #please explain how this statement works
        
        
    # def write_to_buffer_with_dots(self, s):  ###commented out since not needed at present

      # len_s = len(s)

      # x = 0
      # i = 0
      # while i < len_s:

        # if x >= 8:
          # break

        # elif i < (len_s - 1) and s[i+1] == '.':
          # self.buffer[7-x] = self.decode_char(s[i]) | 0x80
          # i += 1
        # else:
          # self.buffer[7-x] = self.decode_char(s[i])

        # x += 1
        # i += 1

      # while x < 8:
        # self.buffer[7-x] = self.decode_char(' ')
        # x += 1

    def display(self):
        for i in range(0,8):
            self.set_register(REG_DIGIT_BASE + i, self.buffer[i])

    def set_intensity(self, i):
        self.intensity = i
        self.set_register(REG_INTENSITY, self.intensity)
```

I  tried using the code as it is, but was not able to get any display. Then I thought that the statement from machine import Pin, SPI was not proper, since using SOFTSPI. So I changed this to from machine import Pin, SoftSPI. However, even after many tries I am not successful. Please advise, what I should do. I would like to learn using SPI.

Comment: Where is it managing the "load" signal on pin 12?

Comment: `bytearray`, as the name implies, creates a byte array from the list of values supplied.  `spi.write` accepts such an array, and writes all of the bytes inside the array.